# Python изменение формы картинки

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, масштабирование

Как с помощью python менять форму изображения на подобие различных графических редакторов? (пример на изображении ниже). Нужно растянуть картинку в разных углах по заданным значениям (интерактивность не нужна, т.е. это будет делаться только в коде)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ниже статья, которая содержит матричные уравнения преобразования для "скольжения" по осям картинки.

### Скольжение в направление оси x

Когда сдвиг выполняется в направлении оси `x`, границы изображения, параллельные оси `x`, сохраняют свое положение, а края, параллельные оси `y`, меняют свое положение в зависимости от коэффициента сдвига:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Скольжение в направление оси Y

Когда сдвиг выполняется в направлении оси `y`, границы изображения, параллельные оси `y`, сохраняют свое положение, а края, параллельные оси `x`, меняют свое положение в зависимости от коэффициента сдвига.

Матричное уравнение для скольжения показано ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже приведен код для скольжения:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# читать входное изображение
img = cv2.imread("chelyabinsk.jpg")
# конвертировать из BGR в RGB, чтобы мы могли построить график с помощью matplotlib
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# отключить оси x и y
plt.axis('off')
# показать изображение
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
# получить форму изображения
rows, cols, dim = img.shape
# матрицы преобразования для сдвига
# сдвиг, примененный к оси x
M = np.float32([ [1, 0.5, 0],
               [0, 1  , 0],
              [0, 0  , 1] ])
# сдвиг, примененный к оси Y
# M = np.float32([ [1,   0, 0],
#                 [0.5, 1, 0],
#                 [0,   0, 1] ])
# применяем перспективное преобразование к изображению
sheared_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(int(cols*1.5),int(rows*1.5)))
# отключить оси x и y
plt.axis('off')
# show the resulting image
plt.imshow(sheared_img)
plt.show()
# сохраняем получившееся изображение на диск
plt.imsave("chelyabinsk_sheared.jpg", sheared_img)
```

Первая матрица — это сдвиг, примененный к оси `x`, если вы хотите ось `y`, то закомментируйте первую матрицу и раскомментируйте вторую.

Скольжение изображения по оси `x`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скольжение изображения по оси `y`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник](https://waksoft.susu.ru/2021/05/23/obrabotka-izobrazhenij-s-ispolzovaniem-opencv-v-python/#Shearing_xaxis)